# use one mysqli connection for many queries in a page

Tags: connection, mysqli

there are two php files . file1 is executed by browser. second has functions that are called on ajax calls. till now i was using mysql_query . so i created a connection object only once in file2 . i wrote a stored proc now and as i couldnt execute it with mysql_query i went for 'mysqli_stmt_init' . the php function that executes the stored procedure runs in a loop of ajax calls continuously . i created mysqli connection object only once in file2 as i did for mysql connection object. it didnt work . so i create a mysqli connection object each time that particular php func is called . suggest a better way

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thats what you're asking for, but you can define new mysqli object only once and then use it in all included code, functions (just remember to pass it as argument or use `global`.

```
$mysqli_connection = new MySQLi([details]);

while (1){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = $mysqli_connection->query($query);
}
```

Above pseudocode will execute all the queries using the same connection.